# Explore the convergence of a series

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, limits, convergence-divergence

I have to explore the convergence of a series. At this picture I used radical Cauchy indication. But I don't now what to do with a denominator to find a limit. Help me please !

[image]

Thank You so much :)

Comment: The first equality sign is nonsensical, and I'm almost sure you didn't mean it.

Comment: @DonAntonio to tell the truth. I have a tasks in PDF format and denominator in first equality can be like this: sqrt(n) ^ 9*....

Comment: What I meant is that the first equality means that the sum of the left hand series equals the right hand limit, which is nonsense. You meant, I suppose, that the limit checks whether the left series converges or not, and **not** that it is its sum!

Comment: @DonAntonio Understood, I just tried to show you the steps :)

Comment: If the question is: "what expression should I replace the question mark symbol" answer would be : $\large \lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}{9^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}}}$ or simply $1$. It's unfortunate that the root test is inconclusive :(

Answer (score 1):

The root test in this case is inconclusive. However, the series converges. Indeed, already the series $\sum \frac{1}{9^{\sqrt{n}}}$ converges. We can show this by (limit) comparison with $\sum \frac{1}{n^2}$.

The intuition here is that in the long run, $9^{\sqrt{n}}$ is (much) bigger than $n^2$. More formally, $\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{x^2}{9^{\sqrt{x}}}=0$.

This becomes obvious if we let $\sqrt{x}=t$, and note that $9\gt e$. So 
$\frac{x^2}{9^{\sqrt{x}}}\lt \frac{t^4}{e^t}$, and we know that $\lim_{t\to\infty} \frac{t^4}{e^t}=0$.

**Remark:** There is a "cleverer" way to solve the problem. Consider the integral
$$\int_1^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}9^{\sqrt{x}}}\,dx.$$
This integral obviously converges (make the substitution $u=\sqrt{x}$), so by the Integral Test our original series converges.

Cute, but I do not like it as much as the cruder argument of the answer. That is because the answer confronts the issue of the "size" of the $n$-th term in a more direct way.

Answer (score 1):

$$9^{1/\sqrt n}=e^{\frac1{\sqrt n}\log 9}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}e^0=1\implies$$

$$\sqrt[n]{\frac1{\sqrt n\, 9^{\sqrt n}}}=\frac1{n^{1/2n}\,9^{1/\sqrt n}}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}1$$

so the $\;n$-th root test doesn't help here.

Comment: Yes, but the  *Ratio Test* does. Or have I made a mistake in my elementary answer?

Comment: I think you have, @Frank . Read my comment under your answer.

Comment: Yes you are right, many thanks for pointing out this very silly mistake!

Comment: Any time, @Frank...and welcome to the "Damn, how could I possibly write that nonsense there!" club . I'm honorary president and founder. :)